# Introspection of Lambda expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I want to "look inside" a lambda expression without evaluating it.
Given an expression such as the one here,

```
(lambda something: something.x > something.y)
```

I would like to access the elements that are accessed outside the `lambda`. (I.e. return a list with references to `something.x` and `something.y`.

However, as my expressions can have side-effects, (`lambda self: self.set_value(15)`) I want to do this without actually calling the expression. This requirement voids the possibility to override `__getattr__` in the object that is being passed into the `lambda`.

Short example:

```
l = (lambda something: something.x > something.y)
something = Something()
elements = l.get_accessed_elements(something)
# elements is a list where
# elements[0] points to something.x, and
# elements[1] points to something.y
```

I looked into parsing the body myself, but I would have to access the source code and do some string magic to clean the source-lines (gathered via `inspect`).

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give a concrete example explaining it?

Comment: Are you looking to figure out that `x` and `y` are accessed from the object referred to as `something`, without having the code to the lambda function? If so, you could try overriding the `__getattr__` method in the definition of the class of which `something` is an instance

Comment: `lambda something: print(something) or something.x > something.y`

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into accessing the objects `x` and `y` @inspectorG4dget See my comment on Daniel Roseman's answer below, I'm trying to get the references without actually executing it.

Comment: This is probably a very interesting question, but please edit your question to be significantly more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the disassembled bytecode, although, I think this would require visual inspection:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis((lambda something: something.x > something.y))
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (something)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (something)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (y)
             12 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

You can do this programmatically as well, something to the effect of:

```
>>> bc = dis.Bytecode(lambda something: something.x > something.y)
>>> for instr in bc:
...     if instr.opname == "LOAD_ATTR":
...         print(instr.argval)
...
x
y
>>>
```

Comment: @S.K. Just so you know, the value you get from `LOAD_ATTR` might not correspond to the argument being passed into the lambda, although, `lambda` functions really shouldn't be that complex, but it is a possibility. Heck, anything goes if your `lamda` could potential have side-effects ::shudders::

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with lambda expressions. But if you're trying to see what attribute are accessed, you can always define a custom class with a `__getattribute__` method which prints its arguments:

```
class Something(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print("{} was accessed".format(name))
```

If you now pass that to your lambda expression:

```
>>> l = lambda something: something.x > something.y
>>> s = Something()
>>> l(s)
x was accessed
y was accessed
```

**Edit after comment** It might not work in all cases, but examining the attributes of the `__code__` attribute of the lambda shows a `co_names` attribute which happens to contain `('x', 'y')`. No idea if that will be enough for you.

Comment: I thought of doing something like this. The problem however is that the lambda might have side-effects (e.g. `something.x.setValue(15)`), so a non-intrusive way (i.e. not actually executing it) would be preferable.

Comment: @S.K. How could you possibly know the identity of `something` without calling the `lambda`? You really need to clarify your question with exactly what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga basically @Daniel-Roseman's answer would be half the solution. I could store/update/get a list of `something`'s elements that are accessed. However, for that I would need to call the `lambda`, which would execute the code. But this could/would in many cases change the state of the system. Does this explain my problem?
I was thinking of using some parsing approach, but my python knowledge is not good enough.

Comment: If the lambda contains multiple levels of references (`something.foo.spam.x`, for example), `co_names` will contain each element as a separate item - there's no information there as to how they were chained together.